# compilation error AFNetworking , Semantic issue?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using the tutorial "mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/" for understanding the use of AFNewtworking.
I disabled ARC as suggested,but I think the tutorial is a bit old. Because the latest version of AFNetworking requires ARC ? I tried compiling without ARC and it showed messages saying ARC is required.
I am seeing the following compilation error when I compile with **ARC enabled.**

```
  "/Users/user/Documents/NetworkingisFun/NetworkingisFun/AFNetworking-AFNetworking-215a32e/Example/Classes/AFAppDotNetAPIClient.m:54:40: Use of undeclared identifier 'AFSSLPinningModePublicKey'"
```

Has anyone seen this issue before ?

Answer (score 2):

- add missing variable to your .pch file: 
  #define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicated that you have not #include the header file (.h) containing AFSSLPinningModePublicKey in AFAppDotNetAPIClient.m.